# Freeing multiple Objects in delphi

Tags: delphi

Below, I inserted a code written by Ray Konopka (part of the Coderage presentation). I am planning to use it, however, I am not sure how to clean (on the fly) multiple objects. 
All my attempts were unsucesfull and rendered memory leak.
Any thoughts are appreciated. 
Thanks,

```
  program stringlistDictionary;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
 Classes,
 SysUtils;

 type
   TPlayer = class
  public
   Name: string;
   Position: string;
   Hits: Integer;
   AtBats: Integer;
   constructor Create( Name, Position: string );
 end;


   constructor TPlayer.Create( Name, Position: string );
    begin
      inherited Create;
      Self.Name := Name;
      Self.Position := Position;
      Hits := 0;
      AtBats := 0;
    end;


    var
      Team: TStringList;
      Player, NewPlayer: TPlayer;
      I: Integer;


    function FindPlayer( const Name: string ): TPlayer;
    var
      Idx: Integer;
    begin
      Result := nil;
      if Team.Find( Name, Idx ) then
        Result := TPlayer( Team.Objects[ Idx ] );
    end;


    begin {== Main ==}

      Writeln( 'StringList Dictionary' );
      Writeln( '---------------------' );
      Writeln;

      Team := TStringList.Create;
      try
        NewPlayer := TPlayer.Create( 'Aramis Ramerez', 'Third Base' );
        NewPlayer.Hits := 120;
        NewPlayer.AtBats := 350;

        Team.AddObject( NewPlayer.Name, NewPlayer );

        NewPlayer := TPlayer.Create( 'Derrick Lee', 'First Base' );
        NewPlayer.Hits := 143;
        NewPlayer.AtBats := 329;

        Team.AddObject( NewPlayer.Name, NewPlayer );

        NewPlayer := TPlayer.Create( 'Ryan Theriot', 'Short Stop' );
        NewPlayer.Hits := 87;
        NewPlayer.AtBats := 203;

        Team.AddObject( NewPlayer.Name, NewPlayer );

        Player := FindPlayer( 'Derrick Lee' );
        if Player <> nil then
          Writeln( 'Player Found: ', Player.Name, ', ', Player.Position )
        else
          Writeln( 'Player not found.' );
        Writeln;

        Writeln( 'Active Roster' );
        Writeln( '-------------' );

        for I := 0 to Team.Count - 1 do
          Writeln( TPlayer( Team.Objects[ I ] ).Name, #9,
                   TPlayer( Team.Objects[ I ] ).Position );

        Readln;

      finally
        //!! Need to free the players.
        Team.Free;
      end;

    end.
```

Comment: Other remarks: Self.Name etc. is not needed in the constructor. Why using a console app? Why not use a separate class for the list of players?

Comment: if that's the whole application you *don't* need to free any memory, since you are done with the application anyway

Comment: @BlackTigerX: This looks like a simple illustration.  You're right, for this case, but the real-world code he's trying to use this in is probably a lot more complex.

Comment: Gamecat, "Self.Name" *is* needed in the constructor. Otherwise, the object's Name field won't get set.

Comment: Do you have a link to the presentation? If that comment in the "finally" section was there in Konopka's code, then I wonder whether the omission was the point of the presentation.

Comment: @BlackTiger: I figured to show this Ray's example since my code is much longer but it is based on the same principle.
Except that my fields are private as GameCat suggested. 
@Rob Kennedy:
Rob I do not have a link anymore. I think it was a CodeRage II when Ray actually did this presentation.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, you are correct, its for the name collision. I'm to used to having F prefixes for fields and A prefixes for arguments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Delphi 2009, the TStringList constructor has an optional boolean parameter "OwnsObjects". If you set that to true, the objects are freed automatically.

Else you can do the following:

```
for i := Team.Count-1 downto 0 do begin
  Team.Objects.Free;
end;
Team.Free;
```

And by the way, public fields are discouraged. You beter use properties so you can control what access is possible to the fields. And you can add setter functions to validate the input.

```
type
  TPlayer = class
  private
    FName     : string;
    FPosition : string;
    FHits     : Integer;
    FAtBats   : Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(const AName, APosition: string );

    property Name: string read FName;
    property Position: string read FPosition;
    property Hits: Integer read FHits write FHits;
    property AtBats: Integer read FAtBats write FAtBats;
 end;
```

Comment: THANK YOU. 
I have tested your solution in my applications and all the objects were destroyed. 
I really appreciated.

Comment: I want to correct this answer.
Maybe D2009 introduced new constructor or what - yet the very OwnsObjects property existed at least from Delphi 4 (probably even from 16-bit Delphi 1) and can be turned on/off after creation easily.

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstringlist.ownsobjects.html

Answer (score 4):

Kinda obvious, but still - you don't have to write 'for ... Free' code every time you want to clear TStringList objects. You can put it into a global function.

```
procedure FreeObjects(sl: TStringList);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do 
    sl.Objects[i].Free;
end;

FreeObjects(Team);
```

Or you can put it into a TStringList helper.

```
TStringListHelper = class helper for TStringList
public
  procedure FreeObjects;
end;

procedure TStringListHelper.FreeObjects;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do 
    Objects[i].Free;
end;

Team.FreeObjects;
```

Comment: IIRC, class helpers can be broken easily without even a compiler warning.

Comment: Yes, class helpers are problematic - if you have multiple helpers for one class, the last one will always override all others. Still, they are useful.

Comment: @Gabr: Thanks for the useful code example. I did not know that a class helper can used this way.

Comment: I wouldn't use classhelpers if I had any other choice. In own code (that doesn't interact heavily with the VCL), it is easier to simply create a derivate and override destroy, like Gedean says below.

Answer (score 3):

just a clarification about gamecat answer: I don't know about delphi 2009 but usually the Objects property need an index, and you don't really need a reverse cycle, so:

```
for i := 0 to Team.Count-1 do
  Team.Objects[i].Free;
Team.Free;
```

or:

```
while Team.Count > 0 do
begin
  Team.Objects[0].Free;
  Team.Delete(0);
end;
Team.Free;
```

Comment: Is the "Team.Delete(0);" statement necessary?

Comment: The way he's got it written, yes.

Comment: It's not optimal, specially for large collections. The first code snop is better IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Using D7, I can just subclass TStingList

Comment: Hopefully you can do that in almost any object-oriented language...but thinking about the STL...maybe not